# How to use clause in order in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to get objects via Hibernate from database with concrete order. This order is something like that:

as the first I would like to get objects with column titled for example `first_column` not null,

as the second I would like to get objects with column `second_column` not null,

as the last I would like to get objects which `third_column` is the id for another object/table, and this another object has a field with concrete value for example: `"something"`.

I have created criteria in this way:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("firstColumn"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("secondColumn"));
```

but how can I meet the last requirement?
With the restriction I can do something like that:

```
criteria.createAlias("thirdColumn", "t");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("t.field", "something"));
```

But I have to use order, not restriction with three separate `Criteria` results, because I am using also `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` of the `Criteria` to implement pagination in my frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write the statement in SQL then you can probably get away with the approach mentioned in [this post](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/) which is to create a custom subclass of Order.

Comment: If it can't be written in SQL then it can't be written in the criteria API.  I don't know enough SQL myself to determine whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use the "." separator and write your code as follow

```
criteria.createAlias("thirdColumn", "t");
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("t.field"));
```